# Vectorization of the install_github function from devtools package in R

Tags: r, github, devtools

I am using [`devtools`](https://github.com/hadley/devtools) package to install R packages from GitHub. In the function's manual there is a sentence about `repo` parameter that the function is vectorized on that parameter

> This function is vectorised on repo so you can install multiple packages in a  single command.

I've created 5 packages and I distribute them on a single github repository in 5 different subdirectories. When I use such command to install all 5 of them in a single function call

```
> if (!require(devtools)) {
+    install.packages("devtools")
+    require(devtools)
+ }
> install_github(paste0("mi2-warsaw/RTCGA.data/", 
+                   subdir = paste0("RTCGA.", 
+                                   c("clinical",
+                                     "rnaseq",
+                                     "mutations",
+                                     "cnv",
+                                     "PANCAN12")
+                                  )
+                )
+ )
Downloading github repo mi2-warsaw/RTCGA.data@master
Installing RTCGA.clinical
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ  \
  --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Marcin/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeSTVOR/devtoolse483660419b/mi2-warsaw-RTCGA.data-f38f079/RTCGA.clinical"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'RTCGA.clinical' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
*** arch - i386
*** arch - x64
* DONE (RTCGA.clinical)
Downloading github repo mi2-warsaw/RTCGA.data@master
Installing RTCGA.rnaseq
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-32~1.0/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ  \
  --no-save --no-restore CMD INSTALL  \
  "C:/Users/Marcin/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeSTVOR/devtoolse4839392db6/mi2-warsaw-RTCGA.data-3c044a0/RTCGA.rnaseq"  \
  --library="C:/Users/Marcin/Documents/R/win-library/3.2"  \
  --install-tests 

* installing *source* package 'RTCGA.rnaseq' ...
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
```

it looks like for each single package's installation the whole repository is downloaded. So in a result the whole repository is downloaded 5 times...
Is there a way to download the repository once, and to install 5 packages then - if possible - in a one function call similar to the one I am using?

Comment: not with `devtools`. `install_github` eventually just downloads a zip file and runs `install` on it. [drat](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/drat) might be able to help simplify installs from your structure, but generally it's expected that it's one pkg per repo.

Comment: What if this is a family of packages :)?

Comment: that's where drat comes into play. you can literally make a "mini CRAN" for your package clan.

Comment: How that can be done? Have someone done something like this before?

Comment: As @hrbrmstr says, you may want to look at [drat](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/drat.html) and its various example vignettes. And yes, it has been done and is being done---see for example [ghrr](http://ghrr.github.io/drat).

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen that `drat` is a link on my mobile.